# C# dropping milliseconds from Java SOAP call

Tags: c#, datetime, soap

I have C# code that is calling a third party Java SOAP method. The method returns a list of events. Normally, the event has a timestamp with milliseconds <2014-11-24T06:04:02.699096>. A particular event type however is returned to my C# code without the milliseconds <2014-11-24T00:00:00>. (It is always a day start 00:00:00.) If I make the call from SOAP UI however, the timestamp does have the milliseconds <2014-11-24T00:00:00.000000>.

The problem I have is when I make the next call to the Java method with the timestamp I receive.  If the milliseconds aren't included, 2014-11-24T00:00:00 instead of 2014-11-24T00:00:00.000000, the call returns an error. "Cannot parse the value "2014-11-24T00:00:00" as a date using style "xsd.timestamp.micro"

How can I force C# to include the milliseconds?

I have tried going to a string and back:

```
string timeString = recvdTimestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff");
newTimestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(timeString);
```

using a constructor:

```
newTimestamp = new DateTime(recvdTimestamp.Year,
                            recvdTimestamp.Month,
                            recvdTimestamp.Day,
                            recvdTimestamp.Hour,
                            recvdTimestamp.Minute,
                            recvdTimestamp.Second,
                            0);
```

adding and subtracting time

```
recvdTimestamp = recvdTimestamp.AddTicks(125);
recvdTimestamp = recvdTimestamp.AddTicks(-125);
```

Every time though, my C# routine sends out 2014-11-24T00:00:00, never adding the .000000.

Comment: I think `recvdTimestamp` is an already a `DateTime`, it already have a milliseconds part. Your `.000000` is just a representations of it's miilisecods part with `.ffffff` format. Are you try to parse both `2014-11-24T00:00:00` and `2014-11-24T00:00:00.000000` with `Convert.ToDateTime` method? What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Comment: The timestamp is a DateTime both in the request and the response. I don't touch the the current culture so should be en-US. I have tried parsing both to convert the time.  A string will always show the milliseconds. Whenever I serialize the xml though, the milliseonds are missing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually on the Java side.  After working with Microsoft support, we could see the trailing zero was always in the DateTime field.  It was always dropped when serialized to a string.  In researching for a work around, I discovered this is actually the correct behavior. I found the following in the W3C XML Standards:

From: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime

> 3.2.7.2 Canonical representation
>
> Except for trailing fractional zero digits in the seconds representation, '24:00:00' time representations, and timezone (for timezoned values), the mapping from literals to values is one-to-one. Where there is more than one possible representation, the canonical representation is as follows:
>
> •  The 2-digit numeral representing the hour must not be '24';
>
> •  **The fractional second string, if present, must not end in '0';**
>
> •  For timezoned values, the timezone must be represented with 'Z' (All timezoned dateTime values are UTC.).

Displaying trailing zeroes in the microseconds is actaully not allowed according to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Implement System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable on the class you want to serialize/deserialize.  Add your custom formatting to the read and write methods.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Vehicle")]
public class Vehicle : System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Wheels { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Windows { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public int Doors { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public DateTime ManufactureTimestamp { get; set; }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        while (reader.Read())
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "Wheels":
                    Wheels = reader.ReadString();
                    break;
                case "Windows":
                    Windows = reader.ReadString();
                    break;
                case "Doors":
                    int doors = 0;
                    int.TryParse(reader.ReadString(), out doors);
                    Doors = doors;
                    break;
                case "Engine":
                    Engine = (Engine)Enum.Parse(typeof(Engine), reader.ReadString());
                    break;
                case "ManufactureTimestamp":
                    ManufactureTimestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.ReadString()).ToUniversalTime();
                    break;
            };
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("Wheels", Wheels);
        writer.WriteElementString("Windows", Windows);
        writer.WriteElementString("Doors", Doors.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("Engine", Engine.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("ManufactureTimestamp", ManufactureTimestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff"));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Example usage:

```
    private Vehicle _vehicle = new Vehicle
    {
        Doors = 4,
        Wheels = "22 inch",
        Windows = "Tinted",
        Engine = Engine.V6,
        ManufactureTimestamp = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-11-24T06:04:02.000000")
    };

    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializeObjectToXmlString()
    {
        string xml = XmlSerializationHelper.Serialize<Vehicle>(_vehicle);
        Assert.IsTrue(xml.Contains("<Wheels>22 inch</Wheels>"));
        Assert.IsTrue(xml.Contains("<ManufactureTimestamp>2014-11-24T06:04:02.000000</ManufactureTimestamp>"));
    }
```